# mysql procedure for insert with select from another table

Tags: mysql

I want to create a procedure that creates a course for a user this takes one parameter that is `userid` and the other value will be selected from `tbl_chapter`.there are 27 chapters that are going to be selected and 27 inserts will be executed .insert is going to be like `INSERT INTO tbl_user_chapter(user_id,chapter_id) VALUEs (9 , 1),(9,2),(9,3),...`.
I want something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE createCourse (IN userid_param int)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tbl_user_chapter(tbl_user_chapter.user_id,tbl_user_chapter.chapter_id) VALUE(userid_param , SELECT id FROM tbl_chapter)
END
```

`SELECT id FROM tbl_chapter` will be multiple rows.

I know this is wrong and I need help.

if there is a better way to do this please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the select does not return one row, then don't use the `VALUES( )` syntax. Use `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE createCourse (IN userid int)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tbl_user_chapter(user_id,chapter_id) 
  SELECT userid, id FROM tbl_chapter;
END
```

Make sure `userid` does NOT conflict with a column of the same name in your tbl_chapter table. If a column exists with that name, you should change the IN parameter of the stored procedure.